# Fredholm alternative theorem and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove the following:

Using the fredholm alternative theorem, prove that if a real entries square matrix $A$ is positive-definite (with the definition $ \langle Ax , x \rangle > 0 $ for all $ x \neq 0$ ) then it is invertible.

I know how to prove that with eigenvalue/eigenvector $(x,\lambda)$ easily of course because $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle \lambda x , x \rangle = \lambda \langle x,x\rangle > 0 $ so $ \lambda > 0$ and then $ 0 \notin Sp(A) $ so $A$ is invertible.

So here is what I tried 
I assume $A^T v =  0$ 
But then $ \langle Av,v \rangle = \langle v,A^T v \rangle = 0 $ 
So $ v= 0$ otherwise it would contradict the $ \langle Av,v \rangle > 0 $ when $ v \neq 0$ and then $ \langle v,b \rangle = 0$ 
So here technically you can use that Fredholm alternative theorem and say that $Ax=b$ has a solution. 
The uniqueness can be proved easily by contradiction too given that if 
$Ax_1=Ax_2=b$ with $ x_1-x_2 \neq 0$ then $ \langle A(x_1-x_2),(x_1-x_2) \rangle =\langle b-b, x_1-x_2 \rangle = 0 $ 

while $ \langle A(x_1-x_2),(x_1-x_2) \rangle > 0 $ 
Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the right idea, sure. I would maybe clean it up a bit to make it read a bit easier. For example,

Let $V$ be any Hilbert space (infinite or finite dimensional). We will show that $A:V\to V$ is bijective. First, observe that $A$ is injective since by positive definiteness, we have 
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$$ 
for all $x\neq 0$. Therefore, $Ax=0$ if and only if $x=0$ and, by linearity, $A$ is injective.

Now let $b\in V$ be a nonzero vector in $V$ and consider the equation $Ax=b$. By the Fredholm alternative theorem, this equation has a solution if and only if $\langle y,b\rangle=0$ for all $y$ such that $A^Ty=0$. But if $A^Ty=0$, then 
$$\langle Ay,y\rangle=\langle y,A^Ty\rangle=0$$
and, by positive definiteness, $y=0$. So indeed, $\langle y,b\rangle=0$ for all such $y$. Therefore, $Ax=b$ has a solution and, since $b$ was arbitrary, $A$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This theorem is a bit of an overkill to me, given that injective is enough for square matrix to be invertible ! (In your proof it's not the case because you considered the possible case where V is not finite dimensional)